# HashSet and Dictionary in TypeScript: export of Interface

Tags: dictionary, typescript, collections, hashset

I think I need some feedback on my collection classes - still learning typescript and javascript and these implementations can surely be improved. I am looking forward to any suggestion. I think I do use the generic types in a useful way, any advice here would be appreciated.

The answer I am looking for most is removing the duplicate IHashTable definition from the end of both snippets and moving it to its own file, I cannot get that done it seems. I am even unsure if this IS an interface in the first place. It compiles and works this way, as far as I can see.

The collection types are incomplete and only define the basic most function at the moment. Once I am sure I use the language and its features correct the other functions should not be too difficult.

Here is my HashSet:

```
import { IHashable } from "./IHashable"

export class HashSet<T extends IHashable> {
    private _items: HashTable<T>;

    public constructor() {
        this._items = {};
    }

    public Add(key: T): void {
        let str: string = key.GetHash();
        if (this._items[str] == null) {
            this._items[str] = key;
        }
        else {
            throw new RangeError("Key '" + str + "' already exists.");
        }
    }

    public Contains(key: T): boolean {
        let str: string = key.GetHash();
        return this._items[str] != null;
    }
}

interface HashTable<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}
```

I wonder if I can avoid the checking-before-adding in a way. The javascript-dictionary this relies on does allow duplicates, so to avoid them there is no other way than to check myself?

This is my Dictionary:

```
import { IHashable } from "./IHashable"

export class Dictionary<T1 extends IHashable, T2> {
    private _items: HashTable<KeyValuePair<T1, T2>>;

    public constructor() {
        this._items = {};
    }

    public Add(key: T1, value: T2) {
        let str: string = key.GetHash();
        if (this._items[str] == null) {
            let kvp: KeyValuePair<T1, T2> = new KeyValuePair(key, value);
            this._items[str] = kvp;
        }
        else {
            throw new RangeError("Key '" + str + "' already exists.");
        }
    }

    public ContainsKey(key: T1): boolean {
        let str: string = key.GetHash();
        return this._items[str] != null;
    }

    public Get(key: T1): T2 {
        let str: string = key.GetHash();
        let kvp: KeyValuePair<T1, T2> = this._items[str];
        if (kvp == null) throw new RangeError("Key '" + str + "' not found")
        return kvp.Value;
    }
}

export class KeyValuePair<T1 extends IHashable, T2> {
    private _key: T1;
    private _value: T2;

    public get Key(): T1 { return this._key; }
    public get Value(): T2 { return this._value; }

    public constructor(key: T1, value: T2) {
        this._key = key;
        this._value = value;
    }
}

interface HashTable<T> {
    [key: string]: T;
}
```

Both rely on a definition of IHashable (hashABLE and hashTABLE: I should find other names.)

```
export interface IHashable {
    GetHash(): string;
}
```

The dictionary looks a bit strange, it "wraps" my dictionary into a new type KeyValuePair and then uses this in the javascript dictionary. What I hope to gain by doing this is get my own type for key, in and out, as long as it offers a string by which it can be indexed. - No idea if that makes sense or is completly wrong.

What I am missing is the count of items in the collection, a way to remove items, and a way to iterate over the keys and the values.
Regarding iterating over I will post another question with my implementation of a list and a ForEach over it, hoping iterating the keys or values might be possible in the same way.

Probably the most important question I forgot here: How could the GetHash-Method be build for an own class? I was going to have a static number on my classes, and count up by 1 in the constructor before assign this number to each instance. This would guarantee uniqueness... is there something better?

Thanks for any tip!
Ralf

Comment: As I mentioned in your other question, this seems too broad to make a meaningful answer below.  It is certainly an interesting exercise to try to implement your own collection types.  One major red flag I see is that your collections can only hold one element with a given hash value.  No other Map/Set implementation that I've seen behaves that way.  To fix it, you'll need to store an *array* of elements as your `HashTable` value type.